# Why does _mm_stream_ps produce L1/LL cache misses?

Tags: c, performance, caching, gcc, sse

I'm trying to optimize a computation-intensive algorithm and am kind of stuck at some cache problem. I have a huge buffer which is written occasionally and at random and read only once at the end of the application. Obviously, writing into the buffer produces lots of cache misses and besides pollutes the caches which are afterwards needed again for computation. I tried to use non-temporal move instrinsics, but the cache misses (reported by valgrind and supported by runtime measurements) still occur. However, to further investigate non-temporal moves, I wrote a little test program, which you can see below. Sequential access, large buffer, only writes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

void tim(const char *name, void (*func)()) {
    struct timespec t1, t2;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t1);
    func();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t2);
    printf("%s : %f s.\n", name, (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + (float) (t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec) / 1000000000);
}

const int CACHE_LINE = 64;
const int FACTOR = 1024;
float *arr;
int length;

void func1() {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = 5.0f;
    }
}

void func2() {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        arr[i] = 5.0f;
        arr[i+1] = 5.0f;
        arr[i+2] = 5.0f;
        arr[i+3] = 5.0f;
    }
}

void func3() {
    __m128 buf = _mm_setr_ps(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i], buf);
    }
}

void func4() {
    __m128 buf = _mm_setr_ps(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 16) {
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[4], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[8], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[12], buf);
    }
}

int main() {
    length = CACHE_LINE * FACTOR * FACTOR;

    arr = malloc(length * sizeof(float));
    tim("func1", func1);
    free(arr);

    arr = malloc(length * sizeof(float));
    tim("func2", func2);
    free(arr);

    arr = malloc(length * sizeof(float));
    tim("func3", func3);
    free(arr);

    arr = malloc(length * sizeof(float));
    tim("func4", func4);
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Function 1 is the naive approach, function 2 uses loop unrolling. Function 3 uses movntps, which in fact was inserted in the assembly at least when I checked for -O0. In function 4 I tried to issue several movntps instructions at once to help the CPU do its write combining. I compiled the code with `gcc -g -lrt -std=gnu99 -OX -msse4.1 test.c` where `X` is one of [0..3]. The results are .. interesting to say at best:

```
-O0
func1 : 0.407794 s.
func2 : 0.320891 s.
func3 : 0.161100 s.
func4 : 0.401755 s.
-O1
func1 : 0.194339 s.
func2 : 0.182536 s.
func3 : 0.101712 s.
func4 : 0.383367 s.
-O2
func1 : 0.108488 s.
func2 : 0.088826 s.
func3 : 0.101377 s.
func4 : 0.384106 s.
-O3
func1 : 0.078406 s.
func2 : 0.084927 s.
func3 : 0.102301 s.
func4 : 0.383366 s.
```

As you can see _mm_stream_ps is a little faster than the others when the program is not optimized by gcc but then significantly fails its purpose when gcc optimization is turned on. Valgrind still reports lots of cache write misses.

So, questions are: Why do those (L1+LL) cache misses still occur even if I'm using NTA streaming instructions? Why is especially func4 so slow?! Can someone explain/speculate what is happening here?

Comment: If you are are compiling with optimization enabled you'll need to look at the assembly to really know what is happening.

Comment: I am looking at the assembly, which btw gets more and more difficult to read with each optimization level, but it doesn't tell me why the non-temporal hint is ignored. At least I guess it is ignored as valgrind still reports cache misses where I expect none. Anyway, I know the question is rather unspecific, so I would really appreciate any input on what may happen here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Probably, your benchmark measures mostly memory allocation performance, not only write performance. Your OS may allocate memory pages not in `malloc`, but on first touch, inside your `func*` functions. OS may also do some memory shuffles after large amount of memory is allocated, so any benchmarks, performed just after memory allocations, may be not reliable.
2. Your code has [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) problem: compiler cannot guarantee that your array's pointer does not change in the process of filling this array, so it has to always load `arr` value from memory instead of using a register. This may cost some performance decrease. Easiest way to avoid aliasing is to copy `arr` and `length` to local variables and use only local variables to fill the array. There are many well-known advices to avoid global variables. Aliasing is one of the reasons.
3. `_mm_stream_ps` works better if array is aligned by 64 bytes. In your code no alignment is guaranteed (actually, `malloc` aligns it by 16 bytes). This optimization is noticeable only for short arrays.
4. It is a good idea to call `_mm_mfence` after you finished with `_mm_stream_ps`. This is needed for correctness, not for performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot Evgeny!
1. This is it. I wasn't aware of that. When I changed the code to allocate the memory only once, it dramatically changed runtimes into what I expected initially. func3+4 are about 2-3x faster than func1+2.
2. Can you elaborate on this a little more? I thought aliasing would only be a problem regarding virtual memory <-> physical memory. I don't see where this is an issue here.
3. Ok, so I would have to use valloc() or some other libc specific function? Didn't have any impact on the runtimes. Cache line alignment should help the cpu with write combining, am I right?
4. Ok.

Comment: I added some explanations about aliasing as well as wikipedia link. Cache line alignment allows to correctly use write combining for the first 64 bytes of the array. For alignment you can use several platform-dependent functions, I don't remember all of them right now. Or you can use `(p+63)&~63` trick. Or just ignore alignment if your arrays are always larger than megabytes.

Comment: About the aliasing issue, you should try to pass 'arr' and 'length' as arguments to your functions, instead of having them as globals. This *may* improve the opportunities of optimization for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't func4 be this:

```
void func4() {
    __m128 buf = _mm_setr_ps(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i += 16) {
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i+4], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i+8], buf);
        _mm_stream_ps(&arr[i+12], buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks :-) This takes func4 to about the same results as func3.